# How does hibernate arranges column while creating a table?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, create-table

I have used Hibernate to map Java objects to PostgreSQL database.
UserDetails class is the entity class used to add user.It contains an embedded object called Address.

**UserDetails.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private int userId;
    @Column(name="USER_NAME")
    private String userName;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="JOINED_DATE")
    private Date joinedDate;
    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
}
```

Address object contains detail about address like city,pincode,street and state.

**Address.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class Address {
private String street;
private String city;
private String state;
private String pincode;
}
```

The class containing main method is below:

```
public class HibernateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
    UserDetails user1 = new UserDetails();

    user.setUserName("First User");

    Address newAddress = new Address();
    newAddress.setCity("Pune");
    newAddress.setPincode("411057");
    newAddress.setState("Maharashtra");
    newAddress.setStreet("Hinjewadi");

    user.setAddress(newAddress);
    user.setDescription("just like that");
    user.setJoinedDate(new Date());     
    user1.setUserName("Second User");
    user1.setDescription("great here");
    user1.setJoinedDate(new Date());

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.save(user1);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    user = null;

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    user = session.get(UserDetails.class, 1);
    System.out.println(user.getUserName());
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
}
}
```

The generated SQL query is as below, which shows that columns are not added in the same order in which they were declared.

```
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start 1 increment 1
Hibernate: create table USER_DETAILS (USER_ID int4 not null, city varchar(255), pincode varchar(255), state varchar(255), street varchar(255), DESCRIPTION varchar(255), JOINED_DATE date, USER_NAME varchar(255), primary key (USER_ID))
```

Is there any rule in which columns are added in hibernate?

Comment: I believe it adds columns in the order that corresponding fields are returned by reflection, i. e. no particular order at all

Comment: @SashaSalauyou : what does reflection mean?

Comment: In brief, this is Java API to operate class/object members by their names. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hbm to ddl library` uses reflection to get the fields within a class and according to the documentation the order of the fields is not preserved / guaranteed:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields()

> Returns an array containing Field objects reflecting all the
>   accessible public fields of the class or interface represented by this
>   Class object. **The elements in the array returned are not sorted and
>   are not in any particular order.** This method returns an array of
>   length 0 if the class or interface has no accessible public fields, or
>   if it represents an array class, a primitive type, or void.

I've experienced similar issues when it comes to writing libraries that rely on reflection.

Comment: I have tried to recompile and execute again. It still adds columns in the same way.

Comment: The mysteries or reflection!  "Not in a particular order" is not the same as "not in a consistent order".  You just shouldn't rely on this ordering.

Comment: Is there any way in Hibernate to add columns in a specific manner ?

Comment: Not as far as I know, it looks like a known limitation (https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2396344).  I personally only use `hbm2ddl` to generate the initial schema and then modify it as required after that (there are usually a few things to fix!).

Comment: does that mean that after using hbm2ddl, we need to sort the columns of table before importing any data into the table?